# Show Indent Guide Lines In Xcode

Tags: xcode, indentation, lines

Coming from a background using Visual Studio and Notepad++ I'm used to the indent guides which help to visually enhance sections of code where the curly braces are used,

Xcode (No indent guides)

[image: xcode]

Visual Studio (Nice tidy indent guides)

[image: vs2010]

As you can see from the images above sometimes there are sections of code where multiple levels of curly braces are open and it gets messy without any indent guides.
Are there any options or plugins that will allow xcode to display the indent guides in between sections of code? Like the VS2010 sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode doesn't have this feature (not that I'm aware of) , but it has a (kinda) similar one. If you look closely in a method with a few loops or if structures, each structure gets a black tint on the left side of the editing area (right next to the line numbers).

You can collapse or expand the functions as needed.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. This will have to make do.

Answer (score 8):

In Xcode 10, if you press Command and hover over the structure it will show what is desired. It is not permanent but it helps.  
 [image: Vertical line to show structure star end]

Comment: It's `Option` now.

Answer (score 7):

I've been searching the same but the most similar solution on Xcode 11 is shows invisibles

[image: Example]

Comment: For me the Invisibles are not helping at all.Not even similar to Indentation guides.