# Xcode 9.2 editor vertical indent guides or highlight scopes

Tags: xcode, ide, indentation, text-editor

For Xcode 9.2 theres a way to always show editor vertical indent guides, highlight scopes or some other feature that helps you to watch the current editing scope? Similar to the features on Android Studio that i marked with red arrows in the image:

[image: helping on editor for scope examples]

Or theres a way to make more custom (friendly) Xcode text editor?

Answer (score 1):

I think XCode 9.2 doesn't provide **vertical indent lines** unfortunately. Please see similar question: [Show Indent Guide Lines In Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167825/show-indent-guide-lines-in-xcode)

You could try [Visual Studio Code for Mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for editing which has the **vertical indent line** feature (you need to install Swift language extension for VS Code though before being able to write in Swift).